# Laravel: Generating URL using IP Address instead of http://localhost

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I want to use IP address instead of `http://localhost`.

I tried url('/') but to no avail.

I am a complete newbie please understand.

I changed the `APP_URL` to IP Address but still to no avail.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where are you trying to use this? If it's in the browser please can you show what url you're using to access your site.

Comment: yes in the browser. i want to generate url using the url() method. I am still using localhost  with xampp.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you wanting it to be an ip address rather than a domain? Also, have you tried visiting the site with the ip address rather than localhost?

Comment: yes i tried 127.0.0.1. i want the verify email address to change the domain name into IP Address

Answer (score 4):

You can do like that

```
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

Check you IP address and enter there

Change  app url in .env  and set it ip then rest password  url will be correct

Comment: yes man. but in verify email address the IP Address isnt showing

Answer (score 4):

The url in email templates is the url defined in .env **APP_URL**.

You need to change the value of **APP_URL** and after changing you need to clear config cache by running `php artisan cache:clear` or by manually removing `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file.

You should be careful to restart your queues if you are using queues and also to stop and then start **php artisan serve** if you are running it.

Comment: i used forceUrl though. now i am more complacent that i will get ip address and not the domain.

Comment: Sorry @BilsCrimson! I didn't understand you comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change it in the XML schema and use forceRootUrl(), I cannot remember the exact parameters use you need to pass to it though.